# How to restrict multiple users video connection Tokbox same time?

Tags: javascript, html, tokbox

Code working fine. But multiple users able to access the url same time. Wants restriction for two users.
Is there any function to give the count or restrict more than 2 users?

```
<html>
<body>
  <!-- OpenTok.js library -->
  <script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js"></script>
  <script>
    // credentials
    var apiKey = '46194902';
    var sessionId = '1_MX40NjE5NDkwMn5-MTU4NDg5MzI4Mzg4NH5sWEorV2JZb2RSVGJBT2NtZHp3bTdMcVl-fg';

    var token = 'token value';
      // connect to session
    var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

var publisherOptions = {
  insertMode: 'append',
  width: 400,
  height: 300
};
var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisherContainerElementId', publisherOptions);
//session.publish(publisher);

    // create publisher
    //var publisher = OT.initPublisher();
    session.connect(token, function(err) {
      // publish publisher
      session.publish(publisher);
    });

    // create subscriber
    session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
      session.subscribe(event.stream);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should exclude your api key and other credentials when asking a question

Comment: If the API itself doesn't have a "active viewing count" then you will need to come up with code yourself to address the issue

Comment: Thank You @GetSet. I have not passed all the values. These are dummy values. If someone used same API can suggest.